# Serving a C program via PHP without writing/uploading previlige

Tags: php, c, file, stream

I need to host a C program on a website. The program takes arguments of the location of a file, calculate, and outputs another file with a slightly different name.
Namely

```
> a.exe ../input.txt
```

will generate another file

```
../input.txt.out.txt
```

Both files will be small (less than 10KB). Now when I put it onto the server, I found that uploading or generating files has been disabled on this server.

What I want to ask is, is there a way to pass php stream as files to the C program and make it write to a stream that it thinks as a file, so that no file is actually created on the server? At the end of the day I do not need to keep those files, but just to serve the output as text in the browser.

p.s.: I am aware of php://temp and php://memory, but they cannot be passed to C program as if they are files.
p.s.2: I am not sure whether this is more a C question or php question. Can C takes stream as input instead of files?

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute an application on a server where yo don't have administrative rights. You need a dedicated server.
Also, as I see on your description, the application seems to be a windows executable. Most hosts are linux based, so this windows executable would not run.

Comment: The server is also windows so it would run. So the issue is to find out whether I am allowed to execute exec() via php? Will update after testing.

Comment: The situation is, I can run exec() via php. The application called can use memory, read file, but cannot write. So is there a way to trick C program to read and write from streams? Or maybe to sandbox the application in php (I don't think it possible though).